# Read flat file having array in Azure Data Factory

Tags: arrays, azure-data-factory, readfile

I need to read a pipe delimited file where we have an array repeating 30 times. I need to access these array of elements and change the sequence and send in the output file.

E.g.

```
Tanya|1|Pen|2|Book|3|Eraser
Raj|11|Eraser|22|Bottle
```

In the above example, first field is the Customer name. After that we have an array of items ordered - Order ID and Item name.

Could you please suggest how to read these array elements individually to process these further?

Answer (score 0):

You will be using copy activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline in which the source will be `DelimitedText` dataset and sink will be `JSON` dataset. If your source and destination files are located in Azure Blob Storage, create a Linked Service to connect the files with Azure Data Factory.

The source file dataset properties will look like this. **You need to select Column Delimiter as Pipe (|).**

[image]

The sink file with JSON type dataset settings will look like as shown in below. Just mention the output location path where the file will be saved after conversion.

[image]

**In copy data activity sink tab, select the File pattern as Array of files.** Trigger the pipeline.

[image]

The sample input and output shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, both input and output files are flat files. Input file will be pipe delimited and output file will be tilde(~) delimited.

Comment: But you didn't mentioned in the question that output file will be tilde delimited.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the output file format then you're better off using two (or three) delimiters, one for the person and the other for the order items. If you can get a third then use that to split the order item from the order line.

Assuming the data format:

```js
Person Name | 1:M [Order]
```

And each Order is

```js
order line | item name
```

You can simply ingest the entire row into a single nvarchar(max) column and then use SQL to break out the data you need.

The following is one such example.

```sql
declare @tbl table (d nvarchar(max));
insert into @tbl values('Tanya|1|Pen|2|Book|3|Eraser'),('Raj|11|Eraser|22|Bottle');
declare @base table (id int, person varchar(100),total_orders int, raw_orders varchar(max));
declare @output table (id int, person varchar(100),item_id int, item varchar(100));

with a as
(
select 
    CHARINDEX('|',d) idx
    ,d
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by d) as id /*Or newid()*/
from @tbl
), b as
(
select 
    id
    ,SUBSTRING(d,0,idx) person
    ,SUBSTRING(d,idx+1,LEN(d)-idx+1) order_array
    from a
), c as
(
    select id, person, order_array
    ,(select count(1) from string_split(order_array,'|')) /2 orders 
    from b
)
insert into @base (id,person,total_orders,raw_orders)
select id,person,orders,order_array from c

declare @total_persons int = (select count(1) from @base);
declare @person_enu int = 1;


while @person_enu <= @total_persons
BEGIN
 declare @total_orders int = (select total_orders from @base where id = @person_enu);
 declare @raw_orders nvarchar(max) = (select raw_orders from @base where id = @person_enu);
 declare @order_enu int = 1;
 declare @i int = 1;
 print CONCAT('Person ', @person_enu, '. Total orders: ', @total_orders);
     while @order_enu <= @total_orders
     begin
        --declare @id int = (select value from string_split(@raw_orders,'|',1) where ordinal = @i);
        --declare @val varchar(100) = (select value from string_split(@raw_orders,'|',1) where ordinal = @i+1);
        --print concat('Will process order ',@order_enu);
        --print concat('ID:',@i, ' Value:', @i+1)
        --print concat('ID:',@id, ' Value:', @val)

        INSERT INTO @output (id,person,item_id,item) 
        select b.id,b.person,n.value [item_id], v.value [item] from @base b
            cross apply string_split(b.raw_orders,'|',1) n
            cross apply string_split(b.raw_orders,'|',1) v
        where b.id = @person_enu and n.ordinal = @i and v.ordinal = @i+1;

        set @order_enu +=1;
        set @i+=2;
     end
 set @person_enu += 1;
END
select * from @output;
```

[image]